# Finding duplicate elements in an unsorted array of structs in less then O(n^2) - C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, struct

the struct:

```
struct info{
    int id;
    int time;
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

The array of structs will always follow this conditions:

- The time variable will always be given in a sorted away to it's corresponding id
- It's considered duplicated if the variables: `time`, `x`, `y` are equal and `id` is different
- The search it's done by looking for two different id values

**Example 1:Find the duplicate for the pair - 001 002**

```
struct info *arr = {{002, 10, 30, 40}, {001, 10, 30, 40}, {001, 15, 45, 50}, {001, 20, 23, 37}}
```

**Output:** the duplicate pair would be in position 0 & 1

**Example 2:Find the duplicate for the pair - 001 002**

```
struct info *arr = {{002, 15, 45, 50}, {002, 16, 21, 13}, {001, 10, 30, 40}, {001, 15, 45, 50},}
```

**Output:** the duplicate pair would be in position 0 & 3

**Example 3:Find the duplicate for the pair - 003 004**

```
struct info *arr = {{004, 6, 47, 52}, {003, 6, 47, 52}, {001, 10, 30, 40}, {002, 15, 45, 50},}
```

**Output:** the duplicate pair would be in position 0 & 1

Is it possible to solve this in less then `O(n^2)` time?

Comment: not sure where you got n^2. you need linear search there, just O(n) per  element.  you will get 2*n in the worst case for pair

Comment: If you have the memory: inserting into a hash table (+checking) is O(N)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a simple solution: Sorting the array is `O(n*log(n))`, and finding duplicate entries then is a single loop of complexity `O(n)`. So all together, a complexity of `O(n*log(n))`, which is less than the `O(n^2)` you wanted to beat. Hope it helps.

Comment: and would you sort the array using witch variable? id? any sorting algorithm that you recomend?

Comment: use, for example, `qsort`; write a custom comparison function that sorts according to a combination of `time`, then `x`, then `y`, then `id`. Then two elements with equal `time,x,y` will be right  after each other; compare the `id`s then for such elements to find duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Adding N elements to a hash table can be done in O(N), so it can be done in O(N).

A working demonstration in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

my @infos = (
   { id => '002', time => 10, x => 30, y => 40 },
   { id => '001', time => 10, x => 30, y => 40 },
   { id => '001', time => 15, x => 45, y => 50 },
   { id => '001', time => 20, x => 23, y => 37 },
);

my %seen;
for my $i (0..$#infos) {
   my $info = $infos[$i];
   my $key = join(':', $info->{time}, $info->{x}, $info->{y});
   push @{ $seen{$key} }, $i;
}

for my $matches (values(%seen)) {
   next if @$matches == 1;

   print("Duplicates:\n");
   for my $i (@$matches) {
      my $info = $infos[$i];
      printf("  %d %s %d %d %d\n", $i, @$info{qw( id time x y )});
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Duplicates:
  0: 002 10 30 40
  1: 001 10 30 40
```

Comment: what is, when each element in the list causes a hash collision?  E.g. when the hash function is `h(element) = 0`?

Comment: @ensc, Then a split or a rehashing occurs. Either way, a new hash perturbation key is used to virtually guarantee it won't happen again. You can even try again In the statistically impossible event that all the elements still all go to a single bucket. So yes, O(N) is really only the average case, but it's virtually impossible to exceed the average case.

Comment: Only if a statistically impossible situation happens twice in a row. Even a malicious agent can't make it worse that O(N) if properly written. So, for all intents and purposes, it's O(N).

Comment: `... when the hash function is h(element) = 0` Then: use a different *sane* hash function. (BTW:this fear of collisions is pathological)

Comment: Much better than `O(n log(n)`; and thanks for editing my answer.